# View controller showing no content

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm new to iOS and is trying out the beginner's project of building a calculator. This is where I'm up to:

[image]

I don't know what I did but suddenly the view control panel turned into a blank panel:

[image]

I can't get the original panel back. I have clicked pretty much everything and still can't get it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

click on **Storyboard** and Try to **recover** Back with **ctrl +z**  or Upload your Demo.

Comment: yeah!! its back!! Thank you so much!! But why did the blank panel appear in the first place? it is so annoying

Comment: Sometimes such type of issue occure due to Autolayout. or Accidently you pressed different keys like delete or etc.

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help .

Comment: just did :) god bless you

Answer (score 1):

Can you please confirm if you have provided correct entry point for the main controller and rootview controller in case if you are using navigation controller.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry if my question sounds silly but I just started using xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might have pressed "LaunchScreen.storyboard" instead of "Main.storyboard" accidentally. Do check that !

Comment: I doubled checked and I'm 100% sure that I pressed main.storyboard. This is so frustrating =(

Comment: Do you have any other project with the same name ?

Comment: Did the Xcode force close itself before saving your files ?

Comment: no, it didn't force close itself, but someone has suggested a solution and it worked. But still, thank you very much for your help. I have up voted your answer. Really appreicate you taking time to help out :)

Comment: Yeah I saw :) Good luck with your project ;)